# why same JSON Requests fail in ionic for some sites?

Tags: json, wordpress, ionic-framework

I use these code to get json from wordpress website:

**app.js**

```
(function(){
  var app= angular.module('IKKS', ['ionic','ngCordova']);
app.controller('IKKSctrl',function($http, $scope){

$scope.stories=[];

$http.get('http://ikks.pergig.ir/?json=get_tag_posts&slug=feeding')
  .success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    angular.forEach(response.posts, function(posts){
      $scope.stories.push (posts);    
    });
  });

});
```

and these codes in index.html file

**Index.html**

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
      <div class="list">
        <a class="item item-thumbnail-right" 
        href="{{story.url}}" target="_blank"
        ng-repeat="story in stories">
        <img ng-src="{{story.thumbnail}}" ng-if("story.thumbnail.startwith('http')">
        <h2 class="story-title">{{story.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{story.date}}</p>
        </a>
     </div>
      </ion-content>
```

these code works properly for KSRA.ir dowain but when change it to IKKs.pergig.ir. It gives fallowing error :

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ikks.pergig.ir/?json=get_tag_posts&slug=feeding. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. "

and if CROS extension was enabled it shows following message

app.js:9

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("b6e9798353d6283149378e3eea86cd42");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://ikks.pergig.ir/?json=get_tag_posts&slug=feeding&ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

I don't understand why this happen? the same code was works very well in one domain but in other domain has problems.

one thing else the json request : `http://ikks.pergig.ir/?json=get_tag_posts&slug=feeding` is working well in browsers.

Comment: I think the message is so clear: "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support". Which browser did you use? Or is there any file that prevent javascipt to run?

Comment: I use google Chrome and Canary. if I put the this command " 'http://ikks.pergig.ir/?json=get_tag_posts&slug=feeding' " on the address bar it will show me the json file but in ionic app it is not work also if i change the domain name to an other wordpress site something lile 'http://ksra.ir/?json=get_tag_posts&slug=news' it will return 4 posts in browser and ionnic runtime result.

Answer (score 0):

The only differences between these two domain was their PHP version. It seems in lower versions (5.2 and 5.3) that json api was working very well with good result returning. I couldn't find other reason.